# Adding C# Dll into wix installer and call a function from that DLL

Tags: c#, wix

I have a C# DLL and i want to add that DLL into my wix project and from that DLL, i want to call a function within my wix project and get the value returned from that function and display it in wix installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Custom action and make a reference to that dll.
From that custom action you will pass the values back to installer.

You can start with this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jschaffe/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters/).

Comment: I'm able to call a custom action with parameters, but what about getting the result as per the original question?